# Managed activeX component won't work in internet explorer

Tags: deployment, activex

We have created an ActiveX component in C# and we are placing it on an HTML page served via ASP.NET. The ActiveX is referenced via the tag. The dll sits on the web site in the same folder where the aspx is and all is working nice.

However, we have deployed this to a customer and it doesn't work there. We have setup the .net framework on the clients and all supporting libraries are there. In fact the activeX component works fine there when run via UserControl TestContainer. It just won't work in the web browser - as if activeX was disabled. However, the web site is added as a trusted site in the IE options and activeX is enabled. This is Windows 2003 server.

I followed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555687  and I think we did all we should have, including the CAS policy (although even switching CAS off temporarily didn't help)

Any idea where to look at? Any help would be very appreciated.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The IIS was set to expire everything immediately and that prevented MSIE from using the dll.